# framework requires SDK 'iphoneos14.5' which is not installed- sharpie bind on ios xamarin (visual studio Macbook)

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to generate api files using sharpie on visual studio (mac) and I am getting sdk error. I have installed 4.5 sdk version on xcode. this it the error.

error: Testframework: framework requires SDK 'iphoneos14.5' which is not installed. You may need a newer Xcode.
test@-MacBook-Air TestIOS.iOS % sharpie xcode -sdks
sdk: appletvos15.4     arch: arm64
sdk: iphoneos15.4      arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: ios15.4-macabi    arch: x86_64
sdk: macosx12.3        arch: x86_64
sdk: watchos8.5        arch: armv7k
Test@-MacBook-Air Test.iOS %  sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos15.4 -framework ~/Desktop/Framework/Testframework.framework

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: Testframework: framework requires SDK 'iphoneos14.5' which is not installed. You may need a newer Xcode.
@Test-MacBook-Air Test.iOS %

Comment: what is your xcode version?

Comment: Xcode 13 latest update

Comment: you could post you issue on https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues